# How to use Firebase push messaging depends on the user's account status at the device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've read all the documents of Firebase messaging, 
but in my use case, I don't know how I should implement it...

In my use case :

The **User** can sign in at **multiple** devices. 
Whenever an user has signed in at the specific device, the device should get notified when the user account receives any event.

This might be a little complex, but please take a look at the three situations below :

[image]

Each number of situation:

1. **User A** signs in at **Device 1**, so **Device 1** will get notified for **User A**.
2. Now **User A** signs in at **Device 2** as well, so **both** Device 1 and Device 2 should get notified for User A.
3. Then finally **User B** signs in at **Device 1**, so **Device 1** no longer get notified for **User A**, instead, it will get notified for **User B** now.

The lifetime of the User and the FirebaseInstance Token are different, so how could I make this? (I have a backend server to store the registration Id.)
What's in my brain:

For **1** situation: To simply get the device token and save to the backend database.

For **2** situation: For this situation, I need to create a **RegistrationToken table** for saving multiple device's token with a relationship with User so that one user can own multiple registration tokens.

For **3** situation: Update the relationship to **User B** instead of User A if the token exists in the database.

But I think those solutions will be a hard work and uncommon, please tell me how do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What i will suggest is that when you are registering a new user make a coloum in your database called token to store the firebase device id token 
So when the new user register you will get a new token assigned to its username
Then with every login and log out attempts change the firebase id token
This means that when ever someone will login from any device its token will be updated in database and when the user logout just pass null value to it hence you can ensure that users always get the right token according to usernames

Hope it helps...

Comment: Same as I think, but how could I support the second situation, to send a notification to **multiple devices** at the same time if the user registered at many devices, did u cover this?